# How to install PIP on python2.7 with python3 already installed, in Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, pip

I have already installed both Python 3.9.7 and Python 2.7 in my Windows. I need to install some libraries like scipy to run an old project, which is written in Python2.
It's a kinda big project so I prefer not to edit the syntax and make it compatible with Python3.

I have to install pip on my python2 for installing the required libraries. I tried to use the instructions mentioned [here](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-pip-windows).

But I get this error:

```
c:\users\amerali\appdata\local\temp\tmponnk1_\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:164:
InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail.
You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings                                                                                            
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)",)': /simple/pip/
```

Which occurs 5-6times, then it gives the following error :

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip<21.0 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pip<21.0
```

I tried it with another internet connections as well, but didn't fix it.

Is there any solutions or an alternative way to install pip?

Comment: Why are you using Python2?

Comment: it may need to install newer C/C++ library [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/)

Comment: @Guy The old project which I need to use is written in Python2. It needs many edits to get compatible with Python3.

Comment: Python2 is no longer supported, if you run into an issue it might not be fixable. You should spend the time required and migrate the project https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. Try [Python Launcher for Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows). Instead of `python <something>`  use `py -3 <something>` (runs python 3) or  `py -2 <something>` (runs python 2).